# My Nginx does not trust in the certificate my app sends?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to setup an NGINX server that has SSL and also does client verification. For some reason it's not working. If I try out the certificates between 2 spring boot applications, they work. So certificates are good. I have the following nginx config file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes auto;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        
        ssl_certificate D:/nginx/server.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key D:/nginx/server.pkcs8;

        ssl_verify_client on;
        ssl_trusted_certificate D:/nginx/client.cer;
        ssl_client_certificate D:/nginx/client.cer;

        
        server_name localhost;
        
        location / {            
            return 301 https://www.google.com/ ;
        }
        
        location /api/user {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/api/user ;
        }
        
        location /api/key {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8443/api/key ;
        }
        

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

If I change this `ssl_verify_client on;` to `ssl_verify_client off;` I get the result I expect. So the rest of the configurations should be fine... I started NGINX today, would like to get some help.

Certificates are created by me. No issuer, no certificate chain. Self signed certificates.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which certificate did you add to `ssl_client_certificate`?

Comment: The `client.cer`. This is the certificate my client send whenever making a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The directives `ssl_client_certificate` (and `ssl_trusted_certificate` if you decide to use it) are supposed to contain the CA certificate against which client certificates are verified. Change these directives to point to the file containing the CA certificate which you used to sign your client certificates.

Comment: I used self signed certificates.

Comment: @laklaklak OK, you'll need to create a proper CA then.

Comment: Why would I need? Why would I need a CA to sign another certificate instead just create 2 certificates and for testing/learning purpose use these in nginx...

Comment: @laklaklak Because that is what you are trying to learn!

Comment: Did not help... https://imgur.com/a/Ba9BUbd